# A question about a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, power-series

> Suppose that $p$ is a real polynomial of degree $n$. Prove that for $|x|<1$,
>   $$\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty{p(m)x^m}=h((1-x)^{-1})$$
>   for some  real polynomial $h$ of degree $n+1$ without the constant term.

I have started trying by taking a specific expression of the polynomial $p$, but I have completely lost. I understand that this result generalizes the following identity
$$(1-x)^{-1}=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty{x^m}$$ for $|x|<1$ but couldn't anymore rather thinking about it. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: edited!

Comment: Consider the derivatives of $(1-x)^{-1}$ and the derivatives of the power series.

Comment: @ jgon Yes, this can be done. I did this for a polynomial of degree 2 or 3. But this seems to be more complicated for polynomials of arbitrary degree. Is there any other way of solving it?

Comment: you shouldn't need to find it explicitly if you can show the left hand side's derivatives form a basis for the space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the polynomials 
$$P_0:=1,P_1:=X, P_2:=X(X-1),\dots,P_l:=X(X-1)\dots (X-l+1).$$
Then we may express $p$ as $\sum_{j=0}^nc_jP_j$ for some coefficients $c_j$. Since for $|x|\lt 1$, we have 
$$\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}P_j(m)x^m=\frac{d^j}{dx^j}\left(\frac 1{1-x} \right)  $$
and the later can be expressed as a constant times $(1-x)^{-j-1}$, we get the wanted polynomial $h$ by summing over $j$.

Comment: Isn't $P_k(x)=(x+1)\dotsm (x+k)$ for $k\ge 1$ ?

Comment: No, the minus signs are important here  otherwise the displayed equality would not hold.

Comment: Nice answer !!!